# Unable to read system views in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to execute the following query

```
  SELECT object_id 
  FROM sys.tables 
  WHERE sys.tables.name = 'Projects'
```

as

```
int n = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
      "SELECT object_id from sys.tables where sys.tables.name = 'Projects'")
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get n as always 0

If I use `SqlConnection` and query it using a `SqlCommand` I get the correct results. So why does `DbContext.Database.Connection` not let me execute a plain SQL query?

For simplicity I have removed `SqlParameter`, so I am aware this code is not SQL Injection safe.

Comment: I think your table name doesn't exist. If I run the query (after changing the name to something valid) it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with system views, Entity Framework cannot read value types in SqlQuery. So I had to change it,

```
public class SingleValue<T>{
    public T Value {get;set;}
}

int n = context.Database.SqlQuery<SingleValue<int>>(
  "SELECT object_id as Value from sys.tables where sys.tables.name = 'Projects'")
  .ToList().Select(x=>x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the result of `Database.SqlQuery` should be first converted to list:

Try this:

```
int n = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
  "SELECT object_id from sys.tables where sys.tables.name = 'Projects'")
  .ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No it shouldn't. From the documentation `Note that, just as for LINQ queries, the query is not executed until the results are enumerated`, calling `FirstOrDefault()` also enumerates the query